# Divergence in the initial value problem solved by Ndsolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

here is to ODE I need to solve:

```
 eq=100000 r (-1 + Log[50000/r])^2 m[r]^2 - 4 Log[50000/r]^2 m[r]^6 - 
 800000 r^3 Log[50000/r]^2 m'[r]^2 + 
 400000 r^2 Log[50000/r] m[r] ((-1 + Log[50000/r]) m'[r]+r Log[50000/r] m''[r])


sol = ParametricNDSolve[{eq == 0, m[1] == b, m'[1] == a}, m, {r, 1, 10^5/2 - 1}, {a，b}]
```

with the constraint `a>0`. For any given value `b`(I tried `b=10,11,12,13,14`), I can always find a non-diverging solution for `m[r]` with some particular values of `m'[1]==a` (for example, `a=0.1` will yield a non-diverging solution). However, when I plug in `b=15` or any larger values, no matter what value I enter for `a`, the solution is always diverging. I checked the documentation about Stiffness Detection, but I do not get much help from it.

does anyone have experience about this problem? thanks

Basing on `bbgodfrey's` comment, there is one more point I need to mention, though I do not if it helps resolve the issue. `m[r=10^5/2]` diverges, so I set the boundary at `r=10^5/2-1`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, sorry, there is a typo. I have revised it.

Comment: Probably, your solution actually is growing exponentially for large `r` for `a` small and `b > 14.5`.  Do you have reason to believe otherwise?  By the way, since `b` is a parameter, replace `{a}` by `{a, b}` in the final equation.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, physically, `b` can be much larger value. `b<14.5` does not make any sense for me.

Comment: My guess is that the rapid growth for large `r` is due to the equations rather than to the numerics.  @MichaelE2 would know better than I, however.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, this reminds me that `m[r]` is actually exponentially growing for large `r`. But I do not see how can it be so sensitive to `b`. if this issue is really due to the equation, then there must be an analytic way to figure out the critical value of `b`

Comment: I think @bbgodfrey is probably right, although the DE is complicated or I'm tired.  Here's a simple Euler scheme to investigate: `Block[{a = 0.1, b = 15}, With[{dr = 0.1, d2m = m''[r] /. First@Solve[eq == 0, m''[r]]}, NestList[{#[[1]] + dr, #[[2]] + #[[3]] dr, #[[3]] + d2m dr /. {m[r] -> #[[2]], m'[r] -> #[[3]]} /. {r -> #[[1]]}} &, {1., b, a}, 250]]][[1 ;; ;; 10]]`  The rows of output are `{r, m[r], m'[r]}`.

Comment: @MichaelE2,now I realize it's the physical model I use is incorrect, so I won't be troubled by this divergence. Though mathematically I have no idea why this function is so strange.

Comment: @3c. It's a complicated equation, both nonlinear and second-order, and not easy to understand.